# React Native App not sending requests on mobile data but works on wifi android

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using API in my react native app which uses HTTPS and works fine while connected to wifi but when i switch to mobile data it gives me Error: Network Request Failed.
The issue only occurs in android 10, works with both mobile data and wifi network in android 9 or older

Comment: Are you per chance using a local ip address?

Comment: But that's only for debugging my app is not even working even in release version

Answer (score 0):

I researched a lot what i found was it wasn't react native problem, it was my phone's problem my phone is nsot certified in google play i bought it from someone and it's bootloader is unlocked. When i open my app turn the data off and then on the app works just fine.